# Inequality with too many square roots

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, radicals

I've been trying to prove the following inequality but the square roots really give me a hard time. $$x\leq \sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x^2+2}{4x}\right)^2}+\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{-x}{2(\sqrt{-2(x^2-4)}-3)}\right)^2}$$ for $x\in[1;\sqrt2]$. I found that both sides are equal at $x=\sqrt2$.

Comment: However did you come by this inequality?

Comment: Why did you delete this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4516669/prove-inequality-with-complicated-square-roots?

Comment: Must have been a misclick or something, didn't intend to do that

Comment: Hi Define : $$h\left(x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{-x}{2(\sqrt{-2(x^{2}-4)}-3)}\right)^{2}}}{x}$$,$$g\left(x\right)=\frac{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x^{2}+2}{4x}\right)^{2}}}{x}$$ then we have :$$g(x)\geq \frac{g\left(1\right)-g\left(\sqrt{2}\right)}{1-\sqrt{2}}\left(x-1\right)+g\left(1\right)+0.125\left(x-1\right)\left(x-\sqrt{2}\right)$$ and $$h(x)\geq \frac{\left(h\left(1\right)-h\left(\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{1-\sqrt{2}}\left(x-1\right)+h\left(1\right)$$ on $x\in[1,\sqrt{2}]$ .Good luck :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let
$$A := \frac{x^2 + 2}{4x}$$
and
$$B := \frac{-x}{2(\sqrt{-2(x^2-4)}-3)} = \frac{x}{6 - 2\sqrt{8 - 2x^2}} = \frac{x(6 + 2\sqrt{8 - 2x^2})}{8x^2 + 4}.$$

We have
$$\sqrt{8 - 2x^2} = \frac{(8-2x^2) - 2^2}{\sqrt{8-2x^2} + 2} + 2 \le \frac{4 - 2x^2}{2 + 2} + 2 = 3 - x^2/2$$
and
$$B \le \frac{x[6 + 2(3 - x^2/2)]}{8x^2 + 4} = 
\frac{x(12 - x^2)}{8x^2 + 4} =: C.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$x \le \sqrt{1 - A^2} + \sqrt{1 - C^2}$$
or
$$x/2 - \sqrt{1 - C^2} \le \sqrt{1 - A^2} - x/2$$
or
$$\frac{(x/2)^2 - (1 - C^2)}{x/2 + \sqrt{1 - C^2}} \le \frac{1 - A^2 - (x/2)^2}{\sqrt{1 - A^2} + x/2}.$$

We have
$$1 - A^2 - (x/2)^2 = \frac{(2 - x^2)(5x^2 - 2)}{16x^2} \ge 0 \tag{1}$$
and
$$(x/2)^2 - (1 - C^2) = \frac{(2-x^2)^2(17x^2-4)}{16(2x^2+1)^2} \ge 0. \tag{2}$$

It is easy to prove that $C \le \frac{11}{12}$.
Thus, we have
$$\sqrt{1 - C^2} \ge \sqrt{1 - \frac{121}{144}}
> \frac{\sqrt 2}{5} \ge \frac{x}{5}. \tag{3}$$

Using AM-GM, we have $A \ge \frac{2\sqrt{x^2 \cdot 2}}{4x} = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$. Thus, we have
$$\sqrt{1 - A^2} \le \sqrt{1 - 1/2} < 3/4 \le 3x/4. \tag{4}$$

Using (1)-(4), it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{x/2 + x/5}\cdot \frac{(2-x^2)^2(17x^2-4)}{16(2x^2+1)^2} \le \frac{1}{3x/4 + x/2}\cdot \frac{(2 - x^2)(5x^2 - 2)}{16x^2}.$$

Using $2x^2 + 1 - 3x = (2x - 1)(x - 1) \ge 0$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{1}{x/2 + x/5}\cdot \frac{(2-x^2)^2(17x^2-4)}{16\cdot (3x)^2} \le \frac{1}{3x/4 + x/2}\cdot \frac{(2 - x^2)(5x^2 - 2)}{16x^2}$$
or
$$25(2 - x^2)(17x^2 - 4) \le 126(5x^2 - 2)$$
which is true. (*Hint*: Let $y = x^2 \in [1, 2]$.)

We are done.